# Is there a way I can use a router or make an api so that I do not have the whole code in only one file?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I wanted to make the main page to have a link for the page with the tic-tac-toe game. And I want the tic-tac-toe game code separated from the main code.

So I made a router. The problem is that if I use io.on in the router file it does not work.

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const tic_tac_toe=require('./tic-tac-toe');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const path=require('path');

//app.use(express.static('./home'));
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'front-end/home')));

app.use('/tic-tac-toe',tic_tac_toe);

app.all('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(404).send('Page not found');
})

server.listen(80);
```

```
const express=require('express');
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const router=express.Router();
const path=require('path');

router.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'front-end/tic-tac-toe')));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Socket connection...');
    socket.on('hello from client',(x)=>{
        console.log('connected');
    })

    io.on('hello from client',(socket)=>{
        console.log('vsekjdbvjdfns');
    })
});

module.exports=router;
//module.exports=io;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.